# Combine many Excel files into one

Tags: excel, merge

I am looking for a way to merge many Excel file into one.

I have over 10 files with the same amount of columns and similar info. I know I can open all of them and copy and paste into one, but I am looking for a faster way to do it.

I also know I can change them into .csv files and merge them into one using cmd command.

I would like a way to do it with out having to open all of them.

Comment: Does each file only use one worksheet?

Comment: Are you wanted to copy 10 worksheets into one workbook (10 tabs) or do you want to merge 10 worksheets into 1 worksheet?

Comment: There is only one worksheet per file and I want to merge all 10 of them into one worksheet

Comment: If you were working with csv files instead of Excel files, then you could put them all in the same directory, open a cmd window, navigate to that directory, and type `copy  *.csv combined.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't yet said wether there is only one sheet per file. Anyways, assuming that it is only one (and always the first one), you may be able to work with the code below. Please replace "C:\MyDirectory\MyFiles" with the appropriate path to the folder holding your files.

note: the file opening procedure is not my work. I got help here:
http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

Hope this helps...

```html
'note: the file opening procedure is not my work. I got help here:
'http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

Sub Merge_Files()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim col_no As Long, row_no As Long
Dim arr_ws As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wb1 As Workbook
Dim col_ws1 As Long, row_ws1 As Long

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\MyDirectory\MyFiles")
i = 0
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    i = i + 1
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=objFile
    row_no = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp).Row
    col_no = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr_ws = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(row_no, col_no))
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges = no
    ws1.Activate
        If ws1.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
            row_ws1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            col_ws1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Else
            row_ws1 = 1
            col_ws1 = 1
        End If
    ws1.Range(Cells(row_ws1, 1), Cells(row_ws1 + row_no - 1, col_no)) = arr_ws
    
Next objFile
End Sub
```